# Visual Studio and Terminal Integration (DLL)

Tags: dll, terminal, pos

Anyone please do explain me how create a dll function that will connect to terminal (Ex : Pax A920) and to send/receive data.

Comment: You should contact [technical support](https://marketing.paxtechnology.com/technical-support) for information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.